# Renaming lambda in Common Lisp

Tags: macros, lambda, common-lisp

I started learning Common Lisp recently, and (just for fun) decided to rename the lambda macro.

My attempt was this:

```
> (defmacro λ (args &body body) `(lambda ,args ,@body))
```

It seems to expand correctly when by itself:

```
> (macroexpand-1 '(λ (x) (* x x)))
(LAMBDA (X) (* X X))
```

But when it's nested inside an expression, execution fails:

```
> ((λ (x) (* x x)) 2)
(Λ (X) (* X X)) is not a function name; try using a symbol instead
```

I am probably missing something obvious about macro expansion, but couldn't find out what it is.

Maybe you can help me out?

edit:
It does work with lambda:

```
> ((lambda (x) (* x x)) 2)
4
```

edit 2:
One way to make it work (as suggested by Rainer):

```
> (set-macro-character #\λ (lambda (stream char) (quote lambda)))
```

(tested in Clozure CL)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Common Lisp `LAMBDA` is two different things: a macro and a symbol which can be used in a LAMBDA expression.

The LAMBDA expression:

```
(function (lambda (x) (foo x)))
```

shorter written as

```
#'(lambda (x) (foo x))
```

An applied lambda expression is also valid:

```
((lambda (x) (+ x x)) 4)
```

Above both forms are part of the core syntax of Common Lisp.

Late in the definition of Common Lisp a macro called `LAMBDA` has been added. Confusingly enough, but with good intentions. ;-) It is documented as [Macro LAMBDA](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_lambda.htm).

```
(lambda (x) (+ x x))
```

expands into

```
(function (lambda (x) (+ x x))
```

It makes Common Lisp code look slightly more like Scheme code and then it is not necessary to write

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (+ x x)) some-list)
```

With the `LAMBDA` macro we can write

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) (+ x x)) some-list)
```

Your example fails because

```
((my-lambda (x) (* x x)) 2)
```

is not valid Common Lisp syntax.

Common Lisp expects either

- a data object
- a variable
- a function call in the form `(function args...)`
- a function call in the form `((lambda (arglist ...) body) args...)`
- a macro form like `(macro-name forms...)`
- a special form using one of the built-in special operators like `FUNCTION`, `LET`, ...
  defined in the list of [special operators](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababa.htm#clspecialops) in Common Lisp

As you can see a syntax of

```
((macro-name forms...) forms...)
```

is not a part of Common Lisp.

It is possible to read the character `λ` as `LAMBDA`:

```
(defun λ-reader (stream char)
  (declare (ignore char stream))
  'LAMBDA)

(set-macro-character #\λ #'λ-reader)
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 1 > ((λ (x) (* x x)) 3)
9

CL-USER 2 > '(λ (x) (* x x))
(LAMBDA (X) (* X X))
```

Comment: It's not the `function` in the expansion of `lambda` that is a problem, it's the hard-wired behavior of function applications with `lambda`.  So in your explanation I'd change: "An applied lambda expression is also valid" into "An applied `lambda` expression is also valid (only for `lambda` and not for macros that expand to it)".

Comment: It makes sense now, thanks!
So there's no way to get (λ ...) to emulate a lambda expression?

Comment: @qrl: the ((λ (x) ...) 4) syntax is possible with a read-macro in CL implementations which support that character. The Lisp reader would have to expand λ into LAMBDA.

Comment: Awesome, looks like a good opportunity to get into read-macros.

Answer (score 2):

You might also think of LAMBDA as an operator which, given a term and a list of free variables, returns a function. This p.o.v. takes LAMBDA out of the family of basic functions and elementary macros -- at least as far as the interpreter is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun lambda-char (stream char)
  "A lambda with only ONE arg _"
  (declare (ignore char))
  (let ((codes (read stream nil)))
    `(lambda (_) ,codes)))

(set-macro-character #\λ #'lambda-char t)   
λ(+ 1 2 _) ; => (lambda (_) (+ 1 2 _))
```

Maybe this is more concise, with ONLY ONE arg of _